# PHP: Exporting HTML table to Excel includes entire form?

Tags: php, html, excel

I have a php file which shows an html form, and on submit, creates an html table from mysql data, and exports it to excel.

My issue is that the entire html form is outputted to the excel file along with the table data.

My code is:

```
<html form..>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
//get sql data and create html table in variable (ie $data="<table>..")

header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$file");
echo "$data";}
?>
```

i want only "$data" to show in my .xls, but instead the whole `<form>` is displaying, submit buttons and all.

thank you.

Comment: Thank you @shakti-singh @marcin-cylke @inquam great answers and quick replies! my script now works beautifully!

Answer (score 1):

No output should be sent to the browser before the header call.

Define your html form below the submit process.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
//get sql data and create html table in variable (ie $data="<table>..")

header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$file");
echo "$data";
}
?>

<html form..>
```

Answer (score 0):

All the data written to the output buffer will be included.
Header calls should preferably be done before any output. But in the case of how your file is organised you could do:

```
<html form..>

    <?php if(isset($_POST['submit'])){ 
     //get sql data and create html table in variable (ie $data="<table>..")
     // Clean the output buffer so it won't mess up your excel export 
     ob_clean();

    header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel"); 
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$file"); 
    echo $data; // no need for quotes here since you only echo your variable
    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do your logic in the presentation layer (conditional ifs in your html file) than maybe it would suffice to wrap your form code into

```
if(!isset($_POST['submit'])){
```

Thou the best way would be to redirect the export action to some other script :)